# How do I get CodeLite to find headers for FLTK or wxWidgets (MacOSX)?

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, fltk, codelite

My apologies, I realize this question may be covered in other questions/articles, but I am not very knowledgeable about "under-the-hood" computer workings, and I have only gotten frustrated so far by trying to look up existing answers.
I'm just trying to teach myself some programming, and I'd like to tinker with a GUI. I'm trying to use CodeLite, and trying to make use of either FLTK 1.3.5 or wxWidgets 3.1.3.  I get the sense that I need to do something with

`Project Settings->Compiler->Include Paths, and/or Project Settings->Linker->Libraries Search Path (and ->Libraries), or possibly Environment->environment variables`.

The problem is I don't know exactly what to put, as when I open the folder for either wxW or FLTK there is a sea of files and I don't know what exactly I'm trying to get CodeLite to find. I'm also used to double-clicking icons, and when it says to specify a path I don't know if I'm clear on the syntax for that.
Can someone let me know what to do to simply use
`#include <wx/wx.h>`  or  `#include <Fl/fl.h>`
and not run into any problems?

**CodeLite 12.0.3, MacOSX 10.14.2, clang 1001.0.46.4**

Comment: if you are starting with programming, maybe wxPython will be easier?

Comment: BTW, CodeLite, might have a template to create wxWidgets project...

Comment: It does have a template, but it still doesn't find the files it needs, and I don't know exactly what parts of the wx folder to point my compiler and linker settings to...

Comment: so are you saying that when you create your project from the template, it still doesn't compile? What wx version do you have? Did the project created successfully? What error message did you get?

Comment: wxWidgets 3.1.3.   When I try to compile one of the template wxW projects straight out of the box, it doesn't find the headers.  I've tried doing a lot of manual manipulation in the compiler path and linker path areas, but I don't know exactly what I'm doing, which files in the wxW folder I need to point to, and I still get errors like can't find wxw-config and such...

Comment: did you compile the library or you installed it from somewhere (homebrew)? can you find `wx-config` script anywhere on the hard? Which OSX version do you have?

Comment: There are files named "wx-config.in" and wx-config-inplace.in", both directly within the wxWidgets-3.1.3 folder.

Comment: OSX 10.14.2, and yes, I built wxWidgets with the 'make' command

Comment: Wait, there is an alias file called 'wx-config' within wxWidgets-3.1.3/build-cocoa-debug

Comment: please execute following: `./wx-config --cxxflags` and `./wx-config --libs`. Then you will know what to put inside include directory and Libraries options in the CodeLite,

Comment: Thanks so much Igor!  I think I can finally get started!